# Fail to connect Redis cluster with python

Tags: python, server, redis, redis-cluster

I have setup a redis() cluster on server. when I tried to connect it, the problem showed as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\client.py", line 159, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\connection.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.nodes.initialize()
  File "C:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\rediscluster\nodemanager.py", line 179, in initialize
    raise RedisClusterException("ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {0}".format(node))
rediscluster.exceptions.RedisClusterException: ERROR sending 'cluster slots' command to redis server: {'host': myip, 'port': '9001'}
```

my python code:

```
from rediscluster import StrictRedisCluster

startup_nodes = [{"host":myip,"port":"9001"}]

rc = StrictRedisCluster(startup_nodes=startup_nodes, decode_responses=True)
rc.set("foo", "bar")
print(rc.get("foo"))
```

env:python==2.7 redis==4.0.9

Comment: Where you able to connect to the redis cluster with `redis-cli` ?

Comment: yes, I can use cluster slots to see my cluster info

Comment: the problem was solved. I added the keyword "password" in the StrictRedisCluster function.Hope can help others.

Comment: You should reply to your own question and accept your answer so other's can see it easier too.

Comment: @SZhang what was the solution can you please explain a bit? I am facing the same issue.